# Does the following sentence with "however" make sense?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"You'll like the book, **however** slow you read."

It was the correct answer to the question

"You'll like the book, **____________** slow you read."

in a placement test which I answered pretended wrong with *"no matter how"*.

So I want to know: Does the sentence "You'll like the book, *however* slow you read." make sense? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: [General reference](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=all&q=however+meaning).

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it makes sense, and is common.

That said,  if I were being pedantic about it, I'd prefer your "no matter how" over "however" in this case, because "however" is more formal, and makes it more obvious the next word should really be "slowLY", whereas the informal "no matter how" seems to work just fine with "slow".

Comment: Pedantically, *slow* is an adverb no matter whether it follows *however* or *no matter how*, and should be *slowly* in either case. So I'd say that *however* is just as good an answer as *no matter how*.

Comment: Right; what I was trying to say is that the formality of "however" draws attention to the error.  In other words, the formality of "however" contrasts with the use of the adverb (as opposed to the adjective), whereas the informal "no matter how" is consonant with it.  Another way of putting it: plugging "however" into the blank **made me notice** that the adverb was used; when I first read it with "no matter how", I didn't even notice. Somehow "however" primed my ear to expect the adjective.

Comment: Hmm @PeterShor. I was thinking that using *however*, slow will be an imperative verb asking the addressee to slow down their phase of reading!